# plotting data for different days on a single HH:MM:SS axis

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, timeserieschart

The `DataFrame` has timestamped data and I want to visually compare the daily temporal evolution of the data. If I `groupby` day and plot the graphs; they are obviously displaced horizontaly in time due to differences in their dates.

I want to plot a date agnostic graph of the day wise trends on a time only axis. Towards that end I have resorted to `shift`ing the data back by an appropriate number of days as demonstrated in the following code

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

index1 = pd.date_range('20141201', freq='H', periods=2)
index2 = pd.date_range('20141210', freq='2H', periods=4)
index3 = pd.date_range('20141220', freq='3H', periods=5)

index = index1.append([index2, index3])

df = pd.DataFrame(list(range(1, len(index)+1)), index=index, columns=['a'])

gbyday = df.groupby(df.index.day)

first_day = gbyday.keys.min() # convert all data to this day

plt.figure()
ax = plt.gca()
for n,g in gbyday:
    g.shift(-(n-first_day+1), 'D').plot(ax=ax, style='o-', label=str(n))

plt.show()
```

resulting in the following plot

[image: daily trend time wise]

Question: Is this the pandas way of doing it? In other words how can I achieve this more elegantly?

Answer (score 2):

You can select the `hour` attribute of the index after grouping like this:

```
In [36]: fig, ax = plt.subplots()
In [35]: for label, s in gbyday:
   ....:     ax.plot(s.index.hour, s, 'o-', label=label)
```

[image]

Comment: This solution throws away the 'minutes' and 'seconds' information so that the plot contains hourly trends alone. Of course I understand that one can create a multi-index using `s.index.hour`, `s.index.minute` etc but this is as much work if not more as the code in my question.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a little too late for this answer, but in case anyone is still looking for it.

This solution works on different months (it was an issue if using the code from the original question) and keeps fractional hours.

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

index0 = pd.date_range('20141101', freq='H', periods=2)
index1 = pd.date_range('20141201', freq='H', periods=2)
index2 = pd.date_range('20141210', freq='2H', periods=4)
index3 = pd.date_range('20141220', freq='3H', periods=5)

index = index1.append([index2, index3, index0])
df = pd.DataFrame(list(range(1, len(index)+1)), index=index, columns=['a'])


df['time_hours'] = (df.index - df.index.normalize()) / pd.Timedelta(hours=1)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for n,g in df.groupby(df.index.normalize()):
    ax.plot(g['time_hours'], g['a'], label=n, marker='o')

ax.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```